# robots.txt: Disallow bots to access a given "url depth"

Tags: robots.txt, noindex

I have links with this structure:

- http://www.example.com/tags/**blah**
- http://www.example.com/tags/**blubb**
- http://www.example.com/tags/**blah**/**blubb** (for all items that match BOTH tags)

I want google & co to spider all links that have ONE tag in the URL, but NOT the URLs that have two or more tags.

Currently I use the html meta tag ["robots" -> "noindex, nofollow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971/dynamic-robots-txt) to solve the problem.

Is there a robots.txt solution (that works at least for some search bots) or do I need to continue with "noindex, nofollow" and live with the additional traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it using robots.txt.  [The standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) is pretty narrow (no wildcards, must be at the top level, etc.).

What about disallowing them based on user-agent in your server?

Comment: Disallowing access would result in some kind of HTTP error. Not sure how google reacts to pages with lots of "server error". Not very enthusiastic to try out :)

Comment: Wouldn't have to--you could serve up some cheap static "nothing to see here" page.

Comment: That's true. Would at least be better than to serve the full page.